# Running an x86 project within a solution built for All Users

Tags: c#, activex

My company has an existing solution built using VS 2015 and .NET 4. XAML is used for the UI. The solution builds for Any CPU. I have an integration project that uses Active X to connect to an x86 project created by a different company. I have a Wrapper class that allows me to communicate with this other project, and provides a UI to display medical images returned by them. I also have a test application that is built as an x86 application to confirm that everything is working with the connection.

The problem that I am having is that the Wrapper project needs to be built as an x86 project for it to connect via Active X to the other application. I have confirmed this by trying various configurations with the test app. However, when built as x86, the main code (built as All Users) does not seem to be able to access the Wrapper code (confirmed through logging).

I originally started testing with the Wrapper as a COM object, and that didn't work either. I ported the Wrapper into the main code-base to try to trace it and determine what the issue was, but have not been able to figure anything out.

My question is, how can I access an x86 project from code base built for Any CPU?

Comment: All Users? Maybe you mean AnyCPU?

Comment: If that's the case you can't, if the program loads in 64 bits mode then it can't use a x86 library. You must compile everything as x86.

Comment: @Gusman - Thank you for the correction; I have updated my question. Unfortunately, my company will not change to compiling in x86 exclusively, so I will need to keep searching for some kind of solution.

Comment: Then you will keep searching forever as there's no way to load an x86 assembly by a x64 process. The only workaround I can think is to create a third program that acts as proxy between your primary app and the activex control which conects to the secondary app.